# JFrame/BoxLayout weird size behavior

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jsplitpane

I am trying to set the sizes of my JButtons in a JPanel with BoxLayout correctly, but the behavior is beyond weird. 
It will take the height from JButton.setPreferredSize, but completely ignore the width. This also only works when all buttons are set to the same height. As soon as one is smaller, it will revert all of them to some random minimum size (which isn't even the same for all buttons)

My code is this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(800, 500);

JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JButton bBookmarks = new JButton("Bookmarks");
bBookmarks.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
//more buttons with same size

leftPanel.add(bBookmarks);
//more buttons

JSplitPane mainPanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
mainPanel.setDividerLocation(200);

frame.add(mainPanel);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This creates this image.

[image: this image]

The middle button is always wider than the rest as well. Using frame.pack() doesn't do anything except resizing the frame because the right panel is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Should look like this:

[image]

Comment: If you want all buttons the same size, use a JPanel using a `new GridLayout(1, 0)` to hold the buttons. You can always wrap that JPanel in one that uses BoxLayout if desired

Comment: There should be a single JLabel below the buttons in the same Panel that has a different size.

Comment: Then the JPanel that holds the buttons and the JLabel go into another JPanel that uses a different layout, perhaps BoxLayout, but the key is to nest JPanels

Comment: You may wish to post an image of the desired GUI appearance

Comment: added the image as edit

Comment: BoxLayout will stretch it up until the maximum size if it can. Set the component's maximum size to be equal to the preferred.

Comment: That's weird though, as the BoxLayout made it smaller than its preferred size or even minimum size.

Comment: Tried it by removing the JSplitPane now, same shit, only this time it ignores height and sets width correctly.

Comment: Must have something to do with adding panels to the frame. When I put the buttons directly in the frame, it works. As soon as I add any type of panel, sizing gets completely fucked.

Comment: Please watch your language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide and conquer: break the design into small, easy to layout containers. In this case do not place the buttons directly in the left (`BoxLayout`) container but in a nested `JPanel` using `GridLayout` manager.
This ensures that all buttons have the same size:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //add all buttons to a panel using a GridLayout which shows all components having the same size
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    JButton bBookmarks = new JButton("Bookmarks");  buttons.add(bBookmarks);
    JButton bPlotter = new JButton("Plotter");      buttons.add(bPlotter);
    JButton bShips = new JButton("Ships");          buttons.add(bShips);

    //add buttons and text area to a panel using BoxLayout
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400));
    leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    leftPanel.add(buttons);
    leftPanel.add(new TextArea(10,30));

    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    rightPanel.add(new JLabel("right pane"));

    JSplitPane mainPanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,true, leftPanel, rightPanel);

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

---

[image]

Comment: Still has the problem with resizing unfortunately, I can't get the buttons to display with the proper size.

Comment: The proposed layout shows all buttons having the same size. If you want the left pane to be of certain width add preferred sizes. See my edit.